# Quando minha classe retorna uma nova instância modificada da própria classe ao invés de modificar ela mesma trata-se de algum padrão de projeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou desenvolvendo uma classe que trata-se de uma coleção de valores.
Nela tenho vários métodos que filtram os valores contido nessa coleção. Minha intenção é retornar uma nova instância dessa mesma classe dependendo da modificação que determinado método faz nos itens contidos nessa coleção.

Geralmente, quando vejo desenvolvimento de classes em PHP, não é muito comum se fazer isso, pois geralmente retorna-se o próprio `$this` para fazer referência a `classe` atual.

Para exemplificar minha dúvida, vou demonstrar uma coleção como exemplo:

```
class Collection
{
    protected $items = [];

    public function __construct(array $items = [])
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function filter(\Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->items = array_filter($this->items, $callback);

        return $this;
    }

    public function map(\Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->items = array_map($callback, $this->items, array_keys($this->items));

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Observem que, a cada método, os valores de `$items` são alterados e a própria instância é retornada.

Mas eu já vi na classe [Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Collection.php), do Laravel, alguns método nas classes de Coleção que fazem algo um pouco diferente: Ao invés de retornar a própria instância, retorna-se uma nova instância para os valores modificados.

```
class Collection

{
    protected $items = [];

    public function __construct(array $items = [])
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function filter(\Closure $callback)
    {
        return new static(array_filter($this->items, $callback));
    }

    public function map(\Closure $callback)
    {

        $items = array_map($callback, $this->items, array_keys($this->items));

        return new static($items);
    }

}
```

Observem que no segundo exemplo, é utilizado `new static` ao invés de `$this`.

Entendo muito bem que essa operação faz com que os valores possam ser repassados de uma nova forma, porém sem alterar a referência original.
Alguns casos isso é muito útil.

Sobre essa diferença, eu gostaria de saber:

- Existe algum nome para esse padrão/comportamento determinado na classe do segundo exemplo?
- Usar esse `new static` não seria um problema de estrutura, visto que se eu herdar essa classe, posso mudar o construtor, e `new static` ficaria prejudicado, tendo que ser alterado em todos os métodos?

## Atualização

Para exemplificar a segunda pergunta, vou dar um exemplo. Suponhamos que eu queria herdar a classe `Collection` para criar novas funcionalidades para a mesma. Nessa nova classe quero adicionar dois novos parâmetros ao `construtor`.

```
  class KeyValueCollection extends Collection

  {
         public function __construct(array $keys, array $values)
         {
              parent::construct(array_combine($keys, $values));
         }
  }
```

Quando eu chamar o método `KeyValueCollection::filter` herdado por `Collection`, será gerado um erro, pois `new static` agora está fazendo referência à `KeyValueCollection`, que necessitam de **dois parâmetros** no construtor, e não um.

```
  KeyValueCollection::__construct(array $keys, array $values);
```

Se usar o `new static` é não modificar a própria classe, como poderia contornar esse problema, já que no primeiro caso, `Collection::__construct` precisa de um parâmetro.

Se precisar de tal operação, teria eu que modificar todos os métodos da classe herdada?

Comment: O padrão é [imutabilidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_imut%C3%A1vel), transformações em objetos e estruturas nunca alteram a referência original, ao invés disso elas são aplicadas a um novo objeto/estrutura que é retornado. Isso vem de programação funcional e o objetivo é evitar efeitos colaterais.

Comment: @BrunoRB eu sei que o `Laravel` é um framework bem conceituado, mas não seria errado usar `new static`, já que se alterar o construtor, todas as chamadas teriam que ser também alteradas? Não seria melhor usar o `clone $this` para tal operação?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: @bigown estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade em expressar essa dúvida. Mas o que quero dizer primeiramente é se trata de um padrão "não mudar a própria classe, mas trazer uma instância nova com as modificações "... E depois, se isso não seria um problema de codificação, já que, se eu estender essa classe que sempre cria uma nova instância, com um construtor com parâmetros diferentes, as outras chamadas de new static ficaria prejudicada

Comment: Esta última parte eu não estou entendendo, não sei que problema é este que você está vendo.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e colocar a questão que me está encucando

Comment: Desculpe-me todos. Eu achava que no PHP não era possível definir um comportamento para o construtor através de uma interface, mas é possível sim. Isso resolveu meu problema :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. O padrão é imutabilidade, transformações em objetos e estruturas nunca alteram a referência original, ao invés disso elas são aplicadas a um novo objeto/estrutura que é retornado. Isso vem de programação funcional e o objetivo é evitar efeitos colaterais.
2. Estender uma classe e alterar a assinatura de um método sobrescrito, o construtor neste caso, é considerado uma péssima prática e viola o [princípio da substituição de Liskov](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov), você quebra a possibilidade de se programar para uma interface já que não é garantido que ela e suas implementações tenham as mesmas assinaturas, então eu diria que o uso de `new static` não é um erro de design.